# Blank plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am doing a course in Python (I do not want them to solve the course questions or anything like that) and in this part, the course gives you a code so that you can visualize through graphics the number of robots (x-axis) and time- steps (y-axis), but when I run the code, it just doesn't graph anything. What should I do?

Sorry if it's a silly question but I'm not quite good with python visualization.

Here is some of the code:

```
def showPlot1(title, x_label, y_label):
    """
    What information does the plot produced by this function tell you?
    """
    num_robot_range = range(1, 11)
    times1 = []
    times2 = []
    for num_robots in num_robot_range:
        print("Plotting", num_robots, "robots...")
        times1.append(runSimulation(num_robots, 1.0, 20, 20, 0.8, 20, StandardRobot))
        times2.append(runSimulation(num_robots, 1.0, 20, 20, 0.8, 20, RandomWalkRobot))
    pylab.plot(num_robot_range, times1)
    pylab.plot(num_robot_range, times2)
    pylab.title(title)
    pylab.legend(('StandardRobot', 'RandomWalkRobot'))
    pylab.xlabel(x_label)
    pylab.ylabel(y_label)
    pylab.show()

showPlot1("Title", "Number of robots", "Time-steps")
```

Here is what it shows:

[image: Plot in blank]

Here is what it prints:

```
Plotting 1 robots...
801.95
2019.15
Plotting 2 robots...
387.35
997.35
Plotting 3 robots...
256.4
732.7
Plotting 4 robots...
201.3
430.2
Plotting 5 robots...
158.25
366.3
Plotting 6 robots...
133.15
328.0
Plotting 7 robots...
113.65
276.1
Plotting 8 robots...
100.0
239.9
Plotting 9 robots...
85.9
191.85
Plotting 10 robots...
78.1
162.3
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately that is not _all_ your code, so it is hard to tell what went wrong.  Suggest you debug by reducing the code to find the problem.

Comment: The plot you show has not the correct title, nor the correct axes' labels.  I second Jody in thinking you need to show us a little more of your code. Don't put new code in comments, but [edit] your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a dummy `runSimulation`

```
def runSimulation(nrobots, a,b,c,d,e, randomrobot):
    if randomrobot:
        result = (450+100*rand())/(nrobots*(1+0.05-rand()*0.10))
    else:
        result = (900+200*rand())/(nrobots*(1+0.05-rand()*0.10))
    print("%10.3f"%result, end='')
    return result
```

and, using exactly the `showPlot1` that you posted, I got a perfect plot

[image]

then I removed the `return result` statement from my dummy code and this is what I got (note the axes'limits, the same as in your figure)

[image]

My conclusion, you have not a consequential `return something` in your version of `runSimulation` — please check your code and please let us know if my guess is correct.

Comment: Hi, yes, you were right! I wrote by mistake `return print(sum(results)/len(results))`, on my runSimulation function, I removed the print and now my code works perfectly!  Thank you so much!